# Should we process data in the transmitter class or in the receiver class?

Tags: design

I have a transmitter class which contains raw data which represents physical values (double and int). These values should be taken by a receiver class to display them with logs (string) sorted according to the physical values.

Maybe I think too much but I don't know in which class I should process the data.

If I create all the logs and sort them in the transmitter class before exporting them in the receiver it will be much more easier to develop since I got all data in the transmitter class. However, it may not be the most logical choice since the transmitter class will contain data it won't use.

If I send all the raw data from the transmitter to the receiver it will be a nightmare to process them and sort them but it could be more logical since the receiver needs the data contrary to the transmitter.

Anyone knows if there are some kind of special rules in programming to solve this kind of issue ?

I think I'll take the 1st option which seems way more easy but I wonder if some kind of special design patterns already exist to tackle this.

PS : I program in C++

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include information that defines what you mean by "transmitter" and "receiver"? What about sorting data in the receiver makes it a "nightmare?"

Answer (score 1):

You should process data in a class that has a better name for it than `Transmitter` or `Receiver`. The need for better names comes up frequently in this question.

> I have a transmitter class which contains raw data which represents physical values (double and int)

A class named `Transmitter` shouldn't "contain" raw data. It should Transmit it, or get renamed.

> These values should be taken by a receiver class to display them with logs (string) sorted according to the physical values.

A class named `Receiver` shouldn't display values. It should Receive them, or get renamed.

> If I send all the raw data from the transmitter to the receiver it will be a nightmare to process them and sort them but it could be more logical since the receiver needs the data contrary to the transmitter.

A properly named and tasked `Transmitter` class has no need to know if the data is raw or processed. Feed it what you want transmitted and let it transmit. If that needs to be filtered, compressed, (or sorted?), it can happen before it gets to the `Transmitter`. Your `DataSource` can have that done before the `Transmitter` sees it.

Not sure why sorting should be done before transmission.  Requiring that would force you to have a complete set of data before transmission could start. The only benefit I could see here is if somehow the receiver had fewer resources to do the sorting.

Comment: If I process the data in the Transmitter class, I only need to send an array of strings already sorted. If I want to create this array in the Receiver class, I need to send all the int, double and string from the Transmitter class to the Receiver class and also additional information to know how to sort the output and how to display the data while all of this is already in the Transmitter class. While I'm explaining this, I've just realized it's so much easier to process the data in the Transmitter class that it's what I'll certainly do.

Comment: + sorry if the class names Receiver and Transmitter are bad. They aren't the actual names I use but I can't give them away since the project isn't open source.

Comment: @Tesla123 the test of a good name is if it tells you what does and does not belong inside.